# In ASP.NET using C#, how to manage the login user credentials until user not logout and even after close the browser for log time or days?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new here and I am also a fresher.

I am working on a project in ASP.NET using C#, and I have an issue to manage login user credentials (userid, menu permission etc) for long time/days or after close the browser. And when user again visit the website and url and no need to login again just enter the 4 digit pin and continue work.

Please help me..

Comment: It's not the place where somebody writes code for you. Here your write your problem, what have done, description.

Comment: Using session you can store it and manage it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sir I am already using the session but session will not be work we close the browser. We need to maintain the user credential after close the browser as we have seen in Facebook app we login one time and use again and again